# How do I get the prediction results down to certain numbers?(Classifiying problem in machine learning)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am a newbie to machine learning.I've been dealing with some problems for a few weeks.I hope someone can help here:
I have a dataset which is involve discrete values and rest are same.Here is my data set:

[image: ScreenShot of my dataset]

I have this features :A,B,C,D,E and ı would like to predict: F
I firstly decide my model should be classifing and ı try to managed this model:

```
# first neural network with keras tutorial
from numpy import genfromtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# load the dataset
data = genfromtxt("C:/Users/Kerim/Desktop/data/30bin.csv",dtype=complex 
,delimiter=",")
x = np.zeros((30000,8), dtype=float)

x[:,0:6] = np.array(data[:,0:6],dtype = "float")
x[:,6:8] = np.array(data.imag[:,2:4],dtype = "float")

dataset[:,0:8]=np.array(x[:,0:8],dtype = "float")
y = np.array(dataset[:,5],dtype = "float")

# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)

# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
predictions = model.predict_classes(X)

# summarize the first 5 cases
for i in range(20):
print('%s => %d (expected %d)' % (X[i].tolist(), predictions[i], y[i]))
```

In this code ı get this warning:

> ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
> after removing the cwd from sys.path.

When ı use tanh my accuricy =0.00 and my prediction result: [image: prediction result] Why my prediction result is always same?
Then I only took the real part to deal with the complex number problem later  by making changing loading datapart

```
# load the dataset
dataset  = genfromtxt("C:/Users/Kerim/Desktop/data/30bin.csv",dtype=complex,delimiter=",")
x = np.array(dataset.real[:1000,0:5],dtype = "float")
y = np.array(dataset.real[:1000,5],dtype = "float")
```

And I did some research ı fall in doubt about these subject
1-)Is my choice of error function correct?
2-)I know sigmoid make prediction range of 0-1 and ı decide to use tanh ,Can this function be used to guess the numbers 07,0.8 and 0.9?
3-)what should I do to adjust the prediction results between these three numbers?

Comment: You are talking about classification, but the problem you are defining looks like a regression.

Comment: How?According to my research discrete values should be classification problem.In addition,I though it can be multiouput classification but ı am not sure. ı think 0.7,0.8,0.9  can be diffrent output for my f column, is it true?@Davidmh

Comment: The way you have set it up, it is predicting 0 or 1 (according to the loss) or -1 or 1 (according to the activation). The question that decides if it is classification or regression is: if the true value is 0.7, is 0.9 worse than 0.8? If they are, the outputs are ordered, and it is regression; if they are equally wrong, they are a classification.

Comment: F column is a coeffient and this model is about signaling,ı try to built a code that choose the best coefficient for given input,program should be choose best coeffient for the data.For example  ı have a signal x=1.23+j5.9 and ı downsapmlig it by multiplying 0.9 in this case my new output 0.9x and true prediction is 0.9. If another column created by 0.7 or 0.8 coeffient it will not work.In addition ı try to use categorical lose function in place of binary but it didnt work.Sory my bad English. Thanks your patience.@Davidmh

Comment: The question is if 0.7 is more wrong than 0.8. If that is the case, you should use a linear output and MSE loss to push your predictions towards the right value. If they are all equally wrong, you should predict as categories: a vector of size N with a softmax activation, where each bin corresponds to the probabilities of the right value being 0.7, 0.8, 0.9... Also, split the real and imaginary part into two real columns (or phase and magnitude, depending on your problem), as you are, you are just throwing away the imaginary component.

Comment: Yes it is right 0.7 more wrong than 0.8 if true value is 0.9. If true value is 0.7 then 0.9 more wrong than 0.8. I will try split to real column my complex data and ı will try linear model.Then I will update@Davidmh

Comment: I though about my program can be regression and ı made extras research.I learn a little bit more now ı need to change my model.Can you advise me any source or topic for learn more how can ı find benefit information.In addition ı made some setting according to your suggestion to take imaginery part it is updated loading part.@Davidmh